# What's the relationship between user_access and hook_perm in drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

It seems both of these functions are used to check whether a user has some previledge.

And the difference isn't obvious to me.

Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 8):

If you implement [`hook_perm`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_perm/6) this will define permissions for the given module like this

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_perm().
 */
function yourmodule_perm() {
  return array('can select', 'can update', 'can delete');
}
```

However the permissions per se, mean nothing... One way of controlling what a user can and can't do is [`user_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/6):

```
// @ some other module function
if (user_access('can delete')){
  // delete stuff
} else {
  drupal_access_denied();
}
```

Also, `hook_perm`-defined permissions can be used while setting up your module menu `hook_menu` by doing:

```
// @hook_menu
$items['modulepath'] = array(
    'title'            => 'modulename',
    'page callback'    => 'module_function',
    'access callback'  => 'user_access',
    'access arguments' =>  array('can select'),
    'type'             => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
);
```

Don't forget to configure your user perms at: admin/user/permissions

Comment: while hook_perm defines the permissions available, user_access checks whether the user has the permission enabled (checks whether any of the user roles has the permission enabled in admin/user/permissions)

Answer (score 1):

hook_perm defines the possible permissions then you can go to admin/user/permissions assign the permissions to specific roles and then use user_access whether the user got the permission (belongs to a role which contains the permission).

Answer (score 1):

`hook_perm` lets you add custom permissions through a module. These permissions then appear when configuring user roles. `user_access` is about determining whether a user has access to particular permissions.